# JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.2.0 so slow

Tags: jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.2.0 on a 64 bit windows 7 with 8 GB RAM

It is very slow , usually CPU usage is more than 60% and memory usage more than 1.6 GB
Editing files are very slow ,sometime when i open JDeveloper it will not open before delete Roaming files.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling your anti-virus and see if it helps - some anti-viruses scan every class that JDev loads.

Comment: why JDeveloper is dead slow. All other IDEs are working fine. It is getting stuck in every 15 minutes. Any better solution, please note that I tried your blog posts and others details.

Answer (score 1):

I would dare to say it is usual jDeveloper performance. I use a machine with a hdd and 8gb ram and I can learn a new language while waiting for jDeveloper to render. I tried installing it on my mac hoping the linux/mac version would be better. Nope. My colleague upgraded his machine to ssd and 16gb ram, but still experiences low performance compared to other IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

For me the CPU \ memory usage was fine

For me the issue was: with a large SOAP service in Tools-> Feature the  **SOAP Web Services** feature makes the IDE so slow its unusable.

[image]

Turn it off and all is ok.